# Project Euler #3 gets a Intellisense expression must have integral or unscoped enum type?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to finish Project Euler Problem 3, and I think I've developed an okay solution but it refuses to compile? Why am I getting these errors?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int A, C, D, E, F, Holder2;
    int TheArray[10][10];
    int B = 0;
    double Value = 600851475143, Value2;

    A = 0;
    while (A < 10000)
    {
        Value2 = Value / B++;
        if (Value2 % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << Value2 << endl;
        }

        A++;
    }

    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Error   1   error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double'
```

Comment: The error message couldn't have been any more clear.

Comment: So then you're going to have to give it a bit of a think and figure out how else you can solve this problem.

Comment: @JohnDibling Darn it, I should've known it would have been too easy....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right there in the error:

```
'%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double'
```

You can't use `%` with a double. You want an integer type for both `Value` and `Value2`.

Comment: I understand that, but if I use an int value my problem will never work.

Comment: Then use a long long.

Comment: you don't understand how the function works. It's not an issue about int space, that's obvious. Look how my code works. If I use a value of int that works, my function will never get the correct value because it's only determined by if it has a remainder when divided by 2. Otherwise, it will always print every value and every single one is wrong.

Comment: You asked why you're getting the errors. You're getting the errors because `%` cannot be used with a double.

Comment: Also your algorithm is wrong. I don't know what it's doing, but it's not going to find the prime factors of any number. Try it with `Value = 24`. The prime factors of 24 are 2 and 3. The first time through your loop `B++` is 1, which means `Value2` is 24, and `24 % 2 = 0`, so it'll print 24. Next time through `B++` is 2, which means `Value2` is 12, and `12 % 2 = 0` so it'll print 12. That's not what you want.

Comment: That's what I thought I wanted... Looks like I'm going back to the drawing board. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, just as a tip, if you want to know what the prime factors are of that large number so you can verify the results of your program, just go to Wolfram Alpha and type in "prime factors of 600851475143".

Comment: I'm not going to look at the answer until I'm done (when Project Euler says I'm correct) so far I made the function as if (Value2 % 2 != 0) do this, as a starter so it checks if it is an odd number. Then I will add a nested if statement to narrow it down until I get the correct answer. One problem I'm facing is that I can't compute the modulo of double's. Is using fmod cheating? Should I not use it for whatever reason?

Comment: Well, every non-prime number has prime factors. You don't need to test non-prime factors (like 12, because 12 = 2 * 2 * 3), you only need to test if prime factors divide evenly into your number. Start with 3, then 5, then 7, then 11, and so on. And you only need to test up to the square root of the large number as well, which helps reduce the time necessary to compute. Does that make sense?

Comment: it does, it makes perfect sense. I forgot about using the formula a week back, I'll try to develop a formula for the prime numbers but It's going to be tricky. When I get to the if statement though, I won't be able to calculate it because I'm still going to have to use a double with modulo, which I think I can only use fmod to do.